# Make Vista Volume Control to remember application-level volume level

Tags: windows, windows-vista

Windows Vista has an application-level volume levels for sound devices. There is a *Speaker* (master volume), an "application" *Windows Sounds* and further applications.

What makes the system to *forget* the volume level for *Windows Sounds*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed this also. I'll have my master volume set at a certain place. Then I'll increase only one of the application sliders from within the software in question. Then it seems like the next time I hear a windows beep or some other system sound it is way too loud.

The reason this happens is that the master volume control and application volume controls are not entirely independent of each other.

Do this: Open a few videos or audio apps and open the volume mixer. Lower the master volume control. Then raise the volume in one of the applications and go back to the master volume. You'll notice that the master volume increased as well.

As far as I know this is by design and there is no way to change its behavior.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can find, Vista does not save the settings.  The starting volume is a percentage of the main volume.

I have, however, found some programs that will fix the issue for a price.

http://www.actualsolution.com/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

Not to mention the periodic ear blasts delivered by flash applications in browsers, as volume levels are rarely remembered for browsers.